# Proof of a Part of the Order Limit Theorem for Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following: If $\exists c \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $c \le b_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $c \le b$ (assuming $(b_n)\rightarrow b$)

My method:  Rearranging the inequality, one can write $ 0 \le b_n - c$.  By the algebraic rules for limits, I know that $(b_n-c) \rightarrow (b-c)$ which means $0 \le b-c$.  Rearranging this new inequality, I get $c \le b$, which is what I was trying to prove.

Is this logic right?  The book I have does it slightly different, but it looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct. :) Did the book use proof by contradiction?

Comment: Its correct -- but you are just relying on the equivalent $x_n > 0, x_n \rightarrow x \implies x > 0 $ without proof, which is really the essence of the problem.

Comment: @RRL, I should probably mentioned that assuming $(x_n) \rightarrow x$, if $x_n > 0$ then $x > 0$ was proved in the book.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi I'm a bit unsure at how the book was trying to prove it (it may be the same).  If you are curious, it's in Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott (http://www.mai.liu.se/~betur/Books/Abbott%20-%20Understanding%20Analysis.pdf pg.48)

Comment: He used part (ii) of the theorem, which states that if $a_n\leq b_n$, then $a\leq b$. Now he takes $a_n$ to be the constant sequence $c$ which of course, has a limit $c$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Ahh, I got it!  I had to stare at it for a bit, but it makes sense now.  All we're doing is turning c into a sequence so we can use part (ii) of the theorem.  Thanks Swapnil :-)

Comment: @Rye_yawn:You're welcome. :-)